# CGAL namespace does not contain data_file_path function

Tags: c++, cgal

I am using xubuntu20.04 and trying out to compile an example of cgal. for reference, I am working with AABB_tree. CGAL is header only so I copied the include folder to AABB_tree directory. Followed this [instruction](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/usage.html). when I run make this error is generated-

```
Scanning dependencies of target AABB_segment_3_example
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AABB_segment_3_example.dir/AABB_segment_3_example.cpp.o
[  7%] Linking CXX executable AABB_segment_3_example
[  7%] Built target AABB_segment_3_example
Scanning dependencies of target AABB_custom_indexed_triangle_set_array_example
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AABB_custom_indexed_triangle_set_array_example.dir/AABB_custom_indexed_triangle_set_array_example.cpp.o
[ 14%] Linking CXX executable AABB_custom_indexed_triangle_set_array_example
[ 14%] Built target AABB_custom_indexed_triangle_set_array_example
Scanning dependencies of target AABB_polyhedron_facet_distance_example
[ 17%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AABB_polyhedron_facet_distance_example.dir/AABB_polyhedron_facet_distance_example.cpp.o
[ 21%] Linking CXX executable AABB_polyhedron_facet_distance_example
[ 21%] Built target AABB_polyhedron_facet_distance_example
Scanning dependencies of target AABB_halfedge_graph_edge_example
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AABB_halfedge_graph_edge_example.dir/AABB_halfedge_graph_edge_example.cpp.o
[ 28%] Linking CXX executable AABB_halfedge_graph_edge_example
[ 28%] Built target AABB_halfedge_graph_edge_example
Scanning dependencies of target AABB_cached_bbox_example
[ 32%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AABB_cached_bbox_example.dir/AABB_cached_bbox_example.cpp.o
/home/alvi95/Personal/code/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_cached_bbox_example.cpp: In function ‘void triangle_mesh(std::string)’:
/home/alvi95/Personal/code/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_cached_bbox_example.cpp:30:17: error: ‘read_polygon_mesh’ is not a member of ‘CGAL::IO’
   30 |   if(!CGAL::IO::read_polygon_mesh(fname, tmesh) || CGAL::is_triangle_mesh(tmesh))
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/alvi95/Personal/code/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_cached_bbox_example.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/alvi95/Personal/code/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_cached_bbox_example.cpp:86:54: error: ‘data_file_path’ is not a member of ‘CGAL’
   86 |   triangle_mesh<Polyhedron_3>((argc>1)?argv[1]:CGAL::data_file_path("meshes/tetrahedron.off"));
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/alvi95/Personal/code/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_cached_bbox_example.cpp:89:54: error: ‘data_file_path’ is not a member of ‘CGAL’
   89 |   triangle_mesh<Surface_mesh>((argc>1)?argv[1]:CGAL::data_file_path("meshes/tetrahedron.off"));
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/alvi95/Personal/code/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_cached_bbox_example.cpp:92:50: error: ‘data_file_path’ is not a member of ‘CGAL’
   92 |   surface_mesh_cache_bbox((argc>1)?argv[1]:CGAL::data_file_path("meshes/tetrahedron.off"));
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/AABB_cached_bbox_example.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/AABB_cached_bbox_example.dir/AABB_cached_bbox_example.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:266: CMakeFiles/AABB_cached_bbox_example.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

It looks like cgal namespace does not include a data_file_path function. How to fix the problem? Is there any linking problem exist?

I have copied the meshes/tetrahedron.off to the AABB_tree directory. Since the function does not exist, no way to read it.

Comment: You are probably compiling an example from a recent version of CGAL using the old version of CGAL provided by Ubuntu. You should download the examples from the same version of CGAL that you have. Note that you can read the old documentation by replacing latest with the version number, say https://doc.cgal.org/5.0.2/Manual/usage.html .

Comment: Consider putting this as the answer :)